# Can't find variable: Promise on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, ember.js, safari

I have a site I'm working on that runs perfectly on Chrome for the desktop (**Windows 8.1** & **OS X Mavericks**)

When I run it on **iOS 7** or **Safari 7.0.2** I get an error to the console that states

> Error while loading route: checkIfLoggedIn

the member it specifies at the message is not a route, it is a method that returns a promise.  When I debug through the ember code to figure out what is going wrong I found that it is rejecting the promise with the reason of

> Can't find variable: Promise

I can't post the actual code from my site here, so I set out to create a fiddle that reproduces the error and I was able to come up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/851/

This runs perfectly on Chrome for the desktop (Windows 8.1 & OS X Mavericks), but on iOS 7 or Safari 7.0.2 throws the following error to the console

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

To recap:

- I have tested on Chrome for Windows 8.1 and OS X Mavericks - It works
- I have tested on Chrome for iOS and it does not work
- I have tested on Safari for iOS and OS X Mavericks and it does not work
- I have not tested on Android at all (I don't have access to any devices at this moment)

This leads me to believe that it is a Safari error as (if I recall correctly) Chrome for iOS uses a Safari control to render the page rather than Chromium

This is the code I'm using to generate the error:

```
App.ready = function() {
    var asdf = new Promise(function (resolve) {   
        var i = 1;
        i++;
        resolve.call(this,i);
    }).then(function (result) {
        alert('I: ' + result);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm, I just changed the code to use the fully qualified name: new Ember.RSVP.Promise(...) and it appears to fix it in Safari on my macbook...That sucks as the documentation on Ember's site doesn't use the fully qualified name

Comment: maddening, actually. Thanks for posting the solution

Comment: Ran into this myself, trying to figure out exactly what's responsible for this behavior. Are you using `ember-cli` or just `ember`?

Comment: I'm just using ember myself

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that on Safari you must use the fully qualified name when creating a promise, otherwise it will not work:

```
App.ready = function() {
    var asdf = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {   
        var i = 1;
        i++;
        resolve.call(this,i);
    }).then(function (result) {
        alert('I: ' + result);
    });
};
```

Note the 'new Ember.RSVP.Promise' instead of the 'new Promise'.  This appears to fix it for me.

Comment: If I could give you a *billion upvotes*, you would be getting *a billion upvotes*! Thank you sir!

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you for sharing. Is there any alternative way to avoid that Ember is not defined for other web browsers? because I'm not using jQuery, and Im avoiding to include Ember.js because it's size is very big. Do you know a better way please?

Comment: @tinyCoder I think that question is out of the scope of this post, try posting up a new question to get an answer for that

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you, I already did that and I got a nice answer, for people who need the same, it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922082

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://caniuse.com/promises), there are no promises for iOS Safari 7.1, or Safari 7.

However, they will be getting them in iOS Safari 8 and Safari 8.