# Can't find variable: Promise on iOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, ember.js, promise, mobile-safari

iOS 7 Safari is reporting the error `Can't find variable: Promise`:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
.
.
.
```

White other browsers don't have this issue, I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462396/cant-find-variable-promise-on-safari) where Robert gave a solution to add `new Ember.RSVP.Promise` instead of the `new Promise`.

My problem is that I'm not using jQuery and that makes all browsers return an error that `Ember` is not defined, and I found that adding `Ember.min.js` solves the issue, but that adds extra `129.96 KB` to my page which is not good at all to my project.

I just want to fix the problem for iOS7, and I appreciate if somebody who knows how he tell us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include a polyfill for browsers that don't support promises natively. Here is a light weight one that is easy to use:

https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill

Comment: Awesome! that worked Patrick, thank you very much for helping with this.

Comment: Glad to hear it! ☺️

Answer (score 2):

Your browser just simply doesn't support promises, so you must provide one on your own. It's not very hard to implement promises in javascript, you can use already made code or babel.

If you want to implement promises, you can use this one
https://gist.github.com/unscriptable/814052

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tomir, after including the mentioned script to my header, my promise functions don't work anymore, `no errors`, should I do any modifications else than including the file?