# Aurelia TypeScript application not working in Safari browser 7.1 but working with 8 and above

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

We have created a application using aurelia framework. We are using es6 decorators in aurelia application. The application works fine in chrome and firefox and safari verson 8 and above, but does not working in safari 7.1.

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: you need show the whats not working with Safari and then ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Promises were not yet (fully) implemented in Safari 7.1, so you need to make sure you've included a Promise polyfill. See related question: [Can't find variable: Promise on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462396/cant-find-variable-promise-on-safari)