# html2canvas is not working in Safari browser: Taking Screenshot

Tags: javascript, screenshot, html2canvas

I just want to take a screenshot of any HTML element ( "container" div in my case ).
it works fine in Chrome and Firefox browsers but not in Safari.

Following is how I am doing it:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/HTML_canvas/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Take screenshot of webpage with html2canvas</h1>
<div class="container" id='container' >
    <div style="background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px;">DIV 1</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px;">DIV 2</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; height: 50px; width: 50px;">DIV 3</div>
</div>

<input type='button' id='but_screenshot' value='Take screenshot' onclick='screenshot();'><br/>

<!-- Script -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function screenshot(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('container')).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

it shows the following error in the Safari browser: [image]

and here is the specific part of code of html2canvas.js (it is by-default file I have just used). [image]

Comment: There's no jQuery in your example + [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Try to see if console have an error.

Comment: yes, safari console shows an error, i forgot to mention it in the question. It shows "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise" in html2canvas.js on line:*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find variable: Promise on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462396/cant-find-variable-promise-on-safari)

Comment: No, that case of the variable Promise is different as I have not customized that file "html2canvas.js"

Comment: It seems like you're using some old Safari version which doesn't have Promises. Use Promise polyfill for that.

Comment: _"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise"_ - Safari supports `Promise`s since September **2014** -> https://caniuse.com/promises o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we just have to enable the CORS in safari-mac browser. So, we'll do it by modifying our function `screenshot()` as follows:

```
function screenshot(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('id-screenshot'),{
        allowTaint: true,
        useCORS : true,
    }).then(function(canvas) {
        console.log("canvas: " + canvas);
        document.getElementById('test-s').appendChild(canvas);
    });
}
```